# File shown empty when I downlad from url and try to read it C++ QT

Tags: c++, qt, file

I'm trying download txt file from url and read it in the same function.
When I try to read it, shown empty on QDebug.
I'm monitoring the file in folder and in terminal with debug. When I download the file it shows as 0 kb. Then it reads the file as empty and the size of the file becomes 1kb after reading.The file I downloaded appears to be full in the folder. I guess I need to get some sleep in the part where reading. I tried,

```
QThread::msleep(6000);
```

but same. How can I solve this issue. Here is my code;

```
#include "setting.h"
#include "ui_setting.h"

#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>
#include <QIODevice>
#include <QThread>



setting::setting(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::setting)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);


}

setting::~setting()
{
    delete ui;



}


void setting::httpReadyRead()
{
// this slot gets called every time the QNetworkReply has new data.
// We read all of its new data and write it into the file.
// That way we use less RAM than when reading it at the finished()
// signal of the QNetworkReply
if (file)
    file->write(reply->readAll());
}

//void setting::updateDownloadProgress(qint64 bytesRead, qint64 totalBytes)
//{
//if (httpRequestAborted)
   // return;

//progressDialog->setMaximum(totalBytes);
//progressDialog->setValue(bytesRead);
//}



// During the download progress, it can be canceled
void setting::cancelDownload()
{
httpRequestAborted = true;
reply->abort();
}

// When download finished or canceled, this will be called
void setting::httpDownloadFinished()
{
// when canceled
if (httpRequestAborted) {
    if (file) {
        file->close();
        file->remove();
        delete file;
        file = 0;
    }
    reply->deleteLater();
    progressDialog->hide();
    return;
}

// download finished normally
//progressDialog->hide();
file->flush();
file->close();

// get redirection url
QVariant redirectionTarget = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute);
if (reply->error()) {
    file->remove();
    QMessageBox::information(this, tr("HTTP"),
                             tr("Download failed: %1.")
                             .arg(reply->errorString()));
} else if (!redirectionTarget.isNull()) {
    QUrl newUrl = url.resolved(redirectionTarget.toUrl());
    if (QMessageBox::question(this, tr("HTTP"),
                              tr("Redirect to %1 ?").arg(newUrl.toString()),
                              QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No) == QMessageBox::Yes) {
        url = newUrl;
        reply->deleteLater();
        file->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        file->resize(0);
        startRequest(url);
        return;
    }
} else {
    //QString fileName = QFileInfo(QUrl("http://example.com/test.txt").path()).fileName();

}

reply->deleteLater();
reply = 0;
delete file;
file = 0;
manager = 0;
}

// This will be called when download button is clicked
void setting::startRequest(QUrl url)
{
// get() method posts a request
// to obtain the contents of the target request
// and returns a new QNetworkReply object
// opened for reading which emits
// the readyRead() signal whenever new data arrives.
reply = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(url));

// Whenever more data is received from the network,
// this readyRead() signal is emitted
connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
        this, SLOT(httpReadyRead()));

// Also, downloadProgress() signal is emitted when data is received
connect(reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)),
        this, SLOT(updateDownloadProgress(qint64,qint64)));

// This signal is emitted when the reply has finished processing.
// After this signal is emitted,
// there will be no more updates to the reply's data or metadata.
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()),
        this, SLOT(httpDownloadFinished()));
}


void setting::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

  manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    // get url
    url = "http://example.com/test.txt";

    QFileInfo fileInfo(url.path());
    QString fileName = fileInfo.fileName();

    if (fileName.isEmpty())
        fileName = "test.txt";

    if (QFile::exists(fileName)) {
        if (QMessageBox::question(this, tr("HTTP"),
                tr("There already exists a file called %1 in "
                "the current directory. Overwrite?").arg(fileName),
                QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::No, QMessageBox::No)
                == QMessageBox::No)
                return;
        QFile::remove(fileName);
    }

    file = new QFile(fileName);
    if (!file->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
        QMessageBox::information(this, tr("HTTP"),
                      tr("Unable to save the file %1: %2.")
                      .arg(fileName).arg(file->errorString()));
        delete file;
        file = 0;
        return;

    }

    // used for progressDialog
    // This will be set true when canceled from progress dialog
    httpRequestAborted = false;

   // progressDialog->setWindowTitle(tr("HTTP"));
    //progressDialog->setLabelText(tr("Downloading %1.").arg(fileName));



    startRequest(url);


QThread::msleep(6000);
  QString appDir = QDir::currentPath() + "/test.txt";
  QString version;
qint64 size;
  QFile file(appDir);
  if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
     QTextStream in ( & file);
  
     size = file.size();
      version = in .readLine();
     file.close();

     qDebug() << version;
     qDebug() << size;

   }else{
      qDebug() << "error ";

  }



  }
```

Comment: You can wait for the transfer to finish, not for a fixed interval.

Comment: @thebusybee How can I do that?

Comment: You have the signal `finished` and the slot/callback `httpDownloadFinished` already in your code. Please read documentation and examples provided by Qt for details.

Comment: `// That way we use less RAM than when reading it at the finished()` Did you actually measure your app RAM consumption, or you just guessed? And why is it critical for you to save RAM?